# Getting lat,long from Loactions

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geolocation, latitude-longitude, geocode, google-latitude

I have a data base of 1.5 lac USA locations and for each location I have to find latitude(lat) and longitude(long).

Currently I am using geocode API (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html) for getting lat,long for these locations but there is a limitation that only 2500 locations are to be processed in a single day. But it would be very time consuming to fetch the lat long for 1.5 lac locations  with that as it would take around 45 days to complete this task.

Is there any other API available for getting the lat, long for these 1.5 lac USA locations in a single day.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards

Arun Kumar

Comment: I'm still don't sure what LAC of the many LACs you mean: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAC_(disambiguation)

Comment: @Martin Thurau -- hi Martin. As you know 10 lacs =1 million. so number of locations that i am refereeing here are 0.15 million.

Comment: I didn't know about the lac or Lakh. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh Learned something everyday...

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Google Maps API for Business](https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing), which gives you 100K a day.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. But i have found Yahoo Maps Place Finder API that is free and process 50K locations in day. Here is the link for that http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/geocoder/

http://www.batchgeo.com/en/

then store the geopostions in a database